# Firefox extension is freezing Firefox until request is completed

Tags: firefox, freeze

For some reason the function is freezing along with firefox until it fully retrieve the stream from requested site. Is there any mechanism to prevent freezing, so it works as expected?

in XUL

```
<statusbarpanel id="eee_label" tooltip="eee_tooltip" 
      onclick="eee.retrieve_rate(event);"/>
```

Javascript

```
retrieve_rate: function(e)
 {
  var ajax = null;
  ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open('GET', 'http://site.com', false);
  ajax.onload = function()
  {
   if (ajax.status == 200)
   {
    var regexp = /blabla/g;
    var match = regexp.exec(ajax.responseText);
    while (match != null)
    {
     window.dump('Currency: ' + match[1] + ', Rate: '
                          + match[2] + ', Change: ' +  match[3] + "\n");
     if(match[1] == "USD")
      rate_USD = sprintf("%s:%s", match[1], match[2]);
     if(match[1] == "EUR")
      rate_EUR = sprintf("%s:%s", match[1], match[2]);
     if(match[1] == "RUB")
      rate_RUB = sprintf("%s/%s", match[1], match[2]);
     match = regexp.exec(ajax.responseText);
    }

    var rate = document.getElementById('eee_label');
    rate.label = rate_USD + "  " + rate_EUR + "  " + rate_RUB;
   }
   else
   {

   }
  };
  ajax.send();
```

I tried to put `window.dump()` right after `ajax.send()` and it dumped in the console also after the request is completed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make an asynchronous AJAX request by passing `true` as the last parameter to `ajax.open`.

Note that once you do that, the `send` function will return  immediately, and any code after it will run before the request finishes.